# Django - How to share configuration constants within an app?

Tags: python, django, coding-style, constants

It is sometimes beneficial to share certain constants between various code files in a django application.

Examples:
- Name or location of dump file used in various modules\commands etc
- Debug mode on\off for the entire app
- Site specific configuration

What would be the elegant\pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 6):

There's already a project-wide `settings.py` file. This is the perfect place to put your own custom setttings.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I specifically asked regarding application scope

Comment: @Jonathan: Are you looking for an *app specific* settings file? Something that can be later overridden in a project settings file?

Comment: @Jonathan, you can/should put app specific settings in settings.py, ultimately a project is run on server not app itself

Answer (score 6):

you can provide settings in your settings.py like

```
MY_SETTING = 'value'
```

and in any module you can fetch it like

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.MY_SETTING
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a configuration module.

Configuration.py:  (in your project/app source directory)

```
MYCONST1 = 1
MYCONST2 = "rabbit"
```

Import it from other source files:

```
from Configuration import MYCONST1,MYCONST2
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Django apps are meant to be (more or less) **pluggable**. Therefore, you are not supposed to hack into the code of an app in order to parametrize what you want (it would be quite a mess if you had to do this ! Imagine you want to upgrade an app you downloaded on internet... you would have to re-hack into the code of the new version ?!?).

For this reason you shouldn't add app-level settings at the app level, but rather put them together somewhere in your project-wide `settings.py`.